# Database engine services are missing before installation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

After installing SQL Server 2012 I am unable to connect to the database because of the database engine features (services) are missing while installation on Windows 8.1

I also enabled .net framework 3.5 before installation

Comment: when i installed it on my desktop(win 7) ,it installed perfectly,and working without any issue,so i thinki have correct setup of sql server 2012

Comment: I am not able to find any solution I think i need to reboot my system.And then try sql server 2012 again.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unusual. I would run the install again and select missing features. If that does not work I would uninstall and run reinstall again.

Comment: thnks for ur time benjamin,but i did my homework ,then only i posted this QUESTION